# ffmpeg-X264 encode --BGRA to AVFrame(ffmpeg) and viceversa? for IOS

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, avfoundation, x264

Am working Video Processing in IOS(iphone/ipod/ipad) Using Objective c. i am using AVFoundation Framework to Capture Video . i want to Encode/decode those video frame using ffmpeg-libx264. i have compiled ffmpeg-x264 lib for ios. i got kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA from AVFoundation.

my problem is
1.How to convert  `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` to `AVFrame` for enode using avcodec_encode_video?

2.How to convert  AVFrame to kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA @ decode side  from avcodec_decode_video2?

Please help me to start above process or give path for working tutorial .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use FFMpeg you'll need to use **kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange** rather than kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA and then you can shove it into an AVFrame.  You'll probably also want to convert what you're getting from the iOS camera (**YUVNV12**) to **YUV420P** so you can receive it on other devices that aren't iOS.  If you are just using iOS devices and that's all you care about, you can skip this side of the color conversion and just pack it into the AVFrame.

Since you're already putting it into a YUV format, you can just use **CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(buf,0)** and encode that address.

Once you decode the image, you'll need to change the colors to **BGRA** from **YUV420P**.  If you didn't swap the colors properly in the first place before you encoded it, you'll just change YUVNV12 to BGRA.

Hope this helps a bit.  You can find the proper color conversion algorithms online.